# Regular Expression to check number length using javascript and allowing length between 6 and 8

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check the number length exists between 6 and 8, I tried in many ways but it is not working for me. Can any one help me with these?

My  code:

Method 1:

```
regex = RegExp(/[-]{0,1}[\d{6,8}]*[\.]{0,1}[\d{6,8}]+/g),
```

Method 2:

```
regex = RegExp(/[-]{0,1}[\d]{6,8}*[\.]{0,1}[\d]{6,8}+/g),
```

I have tried above two ways but nothing helped me in achieve this. Please help me with the solution.

Comment: Why people are downvoting the question is correct and the OP showed his tries?

Comment: With your regex in post, do you want to allow six digits before the decimal and after the decimal as well? Also, please add some valid/invalid samples.

Comment: @MaheerAli: Downvoting regex posts seems like a fashion, as I've been seeing since few months since I am active here. I didn't downvote though.

Comment: Please give some examples of valid strings.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi: I dont need decimal validation here ,I just want to get the string with length between 6 and 8 digits

Comment: By the way, instead of writing `rx = RegExp(/\d+/)` it is enough to write `rx = /\d+/`. The `RegExp` function expects a string, but you are giving it a literal regexp `/\d+/`.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi:   Valid Sample: 123456,12345678

Comment: Invalid Sample:123,123456789,123.45678

Comment: @prasanth: You should always add such kind of information in your post, so it is easy for people to get just by reading your post rather than having to dig through comments.

Comment: Is it something like this: `/^-?\d{6,8}(?:\.\d+)?$/` (matches positive and negative values where the main part is 6-8 digits, and optional decimal point with at least one digit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description doesn’t match what your attempts are doing.

Generally You’re using character classes unnecessarily. Try this, which matches numbers between 6 and 8 digits long, optionally preceded by a `-`:

```
regex = RegExp(/-?\d{6,8}/g);
```

If there are other patterns you want to match, describe them, and add examples.

Comment: Thank you .It helped me

Answer (score 4):

If you want to detect strings which have just 8 digits, anywhere, in them, then consider this approach:

```js
var number = "314159.32";
if (/^-?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/.test(number) &&
    /^[0-9]{6,8}$/.test(number.replace(/[.-]/g, ""))) {
        console.log("valid");
}
else {
    console.log("invalid");
}
```

The difficulty of using a single regex here is the optional decimal component, which may or may not appear.  But, assuming the input is a number, and has no decimal component, then the regex pattern needed is easy.

Comment: Notice that this will pass `''` and `null`

Comment: OP wants to include negative numbers also.

Comment: @AZ_ Just use `Math.abs` with the same range.  Same logic should work.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not very clear, please provide some samples of valid strings. But not I can suggest you to use this regex:

```
^\d{6,8}$
```

Comment: must be a number. not anything

Comment: what about the decimals?

Comment: That’s exactly what was meant when you were asked for examples - there was no mention of decimals in your question.